# In Andorid, is it possible to get the Embed Html code of a YouTube video link?

Tags: android, youtube-api

I'm little bit struggle on past few days i can't get good solution for regarding this. My task is **to load the youtube link in an webview**. The given url is [VideoLink](http://%22http://www.youtube.com/v/aLEhh_XpJ-0?version=3&f=videos&app=youtube_gdata%22). I directly load this link through android webview it won't play. When i load the embed code of this link, it successfully loaded. Here my problem is i get the embed code Manually (ie load the url on system browser-> right click -> select copy embed html),but i have lot of links like this. Is it not possible to do manually. Is it possible to get the embed html code of youtube link by programmatically.

Comment: can u explain more with an example link

Answer (score 0):

Why cant you create a httpConection to the URL and read the InputStream in to String and give it to Webview. if you can explain a bit more, i can suggest you a better idea.